# Differentiate 404 from a Rest service from a normal Request in Angular interceptors

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-404, angular-http-interceptors

I'm codifying an interceptor in Angular to treat the 404 responses. When a request comes from a REST service the interceptor must not intercept the request. My main problem is differentiating between when the request comes from a page request or from a REST service request. Currently I'm using the URL in `rejection.config.url` and testing if my REST URL service matches that value. Although this approach is working, I think this is not a good solution. Is there another way or a better way to do that?

**Interceptor code:**

```
angular.module("mainApp").factory("notFoundInterceptor",['$q','$location','$rootScope', function ($q,$location,$rootScope) {
return {
    responseError: function (rejection) {
         function isURLFromRESTService(rejection) {
            var url = /myresturl/; //pattern used to match REST URL
            return url.test(rejection.config.url);
         }  

         if (rejection.status === 404 and !isURLFromRESTService(rejection)) { // Not found
              $rootScope.notFound = {
                  erro: 'Não possível encontrar: ' + $location.url()
              }
              $location.path('/notfound');
         }

        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
};}]);
```

Comment: The URL of the request is available as `response.config.url`.

Comment: Yes, @georgeawg. You're correct. I'm using the `response.config.url`value to treat when a request comes from REST services. I'm seaching for a pattern in URL. But I think this is not a best solution.

Comment: The more straight forward approach is to put a `.catch` handler in an AngularJS service that makes the $http request to the REST API on the server.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have so far ... so that ppl can understand what you are doing and take it ahead. For that matter its not clear to me what do you mean by `when the request comes from a page request`?

Comment: Ok, @VivekAthalye. I'll edit my question.

Comment: how about checking the content-type of the response and performing the logic? The api response will have content type as `application/json` where as the ajax made by the application to get templates/js/css etc will be different. But this logic will fail if you are making calls to some json content apart from api calls.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative: can't say if its better or not :-| ... you decide :)

When you invoke your REST API, pass a config object with a flag like:

```
$http.get('REST API URL', { ignore404: true })
```

Now in your interceptor you can check like:

```
if (rejection.status === 404 && !rejection.config.ignore404) { 
    $rootScope.notFound = {
        erro: 'Não possível encontrar: ' + $location.url()
    }
    $location.path('/notfound');
}
```

Of course you will need to pass this config object for each of your REST API calls.

For that you may want to write your own wrapper over `$http` that adds the config object (or just add the `ignore404` property if `config` object is passed from outside) and use this service in place of `$http` while invoking your REST API.